# Jenkins Trigger to build on Tuesday's only if new code has been merged since last build - is it possible?

Tags: jenkins, triggers

Jenkins Trigger to build on Tuesday's only if new code has been merged since last build - is it possible?

If I select two triggers (build periodically + monitor source code repository) will that enable either trigger to build? Rather than require both?

I only want Jenkins to build on Tuesday evenings, if new code has come in since the prior Tuesday.

Comment: Set Poll SCM with a cron mapping for Tuesday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select `Poll SCM` under `Build Triggers` and use this cron expression: `0 17 * * 2`
It checks for changes every Tuesday at 5 PM. A build is triggered only if new changes are detected.